# CustomTabIntent :ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, webview, uiwebview

I'm trying to load a html file from assest folder in CustomTabIntent but i'm getting Exception with log "**android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=**"

```
  private void loadHtml() {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = getAssets().open("demo.html");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();

            String str = new String(buffer);
           // String str = "https://www.google.co.in";
            CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
// set toolbar color and/or setting custom actions before invoking build()
// Once ready, call CustomTabsIntent.Builder.build() to create a CustomTabsIntent
            CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
// and launch the desired Url with CustomTabsIntent.launchUrl()
            customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(str));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It's working fine for web url but when we try to use from assets then it'll not work.

Comment: `launchUrl` opens an URL. You can't pass HTML code to it.

Comment: Maybe try `customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.fromFile(new File("/assests/demo.html"));`

Comment: @GerMex It's not working ..i'm getting error "Unable to load page"

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko Is there is any way to load HTML pages in CustomCromeTab?

Comment: no, there is no way. You can try to save your file to the external storage before opening it like @GerMex suggested, but I'm far not sure that it will work